# React change element style rendered with useState

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a messaging app. I have a useState which is called 'messages' and it renders the messages from a certain chat on the screen. For now, every time a user sends a message, it is added to the messages useState but I want it to just be appended to the messages `<div>`.
How can I append a message to the existing messages without changing the useState?

My main chat code looks somethings like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

export default function Main() {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    
    // Message Managment
    function chatInputPressed(e) {
        if ((e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) && message !== '') { // Check if the user pressed the Enter key
            setMessages(oldMsgs => ([message, ...oldMsgs])); // Insert the new message to the messages useState
            setMessage(''); // Set the message to empty
            
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='Main'>
            <div className='messages'>
                {messages.map(m => (
                    <div key='random-key' className='message' >{m}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                id="message-input" 
                value={ message } 
                onChange={ (e) => setMessage(e.target.value) } 
                onKeyDown={ chatInputPressed } 
            >
            </input>
        </div>

    );
}
```

I want to append a new message `<div>` element to `<div className='messages'>` instead of updating the messages like this `setMessages(oldMsgs => ([message, ...oldMsgs]));`.

Comment: Why do you want to work outside the framework?  It could be done with handlers and the like but you are working against the framework to do it like that.

Comment: I actually have no problem with working inside the framework but I just don't know how to do it. Can you please show an example of how to do so? Thanks.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, instead of using react you want to change the dom directly?
Why you want to change it from using state?

Comment: Because after I append the message and the user gets a socket message from the server that the message has been sent successfully, I want to change the style of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it like below.

1. You can keep a refs array to refer later to each message div element. Then use the index or messageId (create a unique one) to update the styles.

```
const [messageRefs, setMessageRefs] = useState([]);
```

2. create and add a new `ref` for each message submission.

```
  // Message Managment
  function chatInputPressed(e) {
    if ((e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === 13) && message !== "") {
      // Check if the user pressed the Enter key
      setMessageRefs((prev) => [createRef(null), ...prev]);
      setMessages((oldMsgs) => [message, ...oldMsgs]); // Insert the new message to the messages useState
      setMessage(""); // Set the message to empty
    }
  }
```

3. For example if you wanted to change the color of a single message define a handler like below. In your case, it will be a callback for the API call to the backend.

```
  function styleMessage(index) {
    const mssageRef = messageRefs[index]?.current;
    mssageRef.style.color = "red";
  }
```

For example, I have added this as a click handler to each message to alter the color.

[image: Edit modest-cray-r6y3y6]